# How to make a required field Disable on a certain view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, required-field

In my ASP.NET Core application, I have a `BassModel` class.

In it, I have a field that is marked as required:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required field")]
public string InputText { get; set; }
```

So all other classes were inherited from this class. Now there is a second class and in that class, I am not passing this value to the controller from the view.

Simply I want to make this required attribute disabled.

I know most people suggest making that parent attribute allow null. But I don't want to do it either. Is there a better approach?

Comment: In my opinion, I don't think you can achieve it instead of setting nullable in father class.

Comment: Make the `InputText` nullable in `BassMode` but make it `abstract`. Then update all your derived classes to implement `InputText` and make it required where necessary.